# Substituting symbols in summation expression in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to substitude symbols in summation and print the evaluated expression, but I'm getting errors when I try to do this.

What is the correct way? Is this possible at all?

I've created a summation expression this way:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.interactive import printing
>>> printing.init_printing()
>>> n = symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)
>>> i = Idx('i', (1, n))
>>> d = IndexedBase('d')
>>> s = Sum(d[i], i)
>>> s
  n       
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   d[i]
  ╱       
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
i = 1
```

When I try to substitude `n` it gives me "TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational".

```
>>> s.subs(n, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 902, in subs
    rv = rv._subs(old, new, **kwargs)
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 95, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 1014, in _subs
    rv = self._eval_subs(old, new)
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/concrete/expr_with_limits.py", line 341, in _eval_subs
    return self.func(func, *limits)
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/concrete/summations.py", line 155, in __new__
    obj = AddWithLimits.__new__(cls, function, *symbols, **assumptions)
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/concrete/expr_with_limits.py", line 368, in __new__
    limits, orientation = _process_limits(*symbols)
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/concrete/expr_with_limits.py", line 59, in _process_limits
    if V[0].upper is not None and not bool(nlim[1] <= V[0].upper):
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

When I try to substitue `d` it produces another error.

```
>>> i = Idx('i', (1, 5))
>>> s = Sum(d[i], i)                     
>>> s
  5       
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   d[i]
  ╱       
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
i = 1
>>> s.subs(d, range(1, 6))
  5                     
 ___                    
 ╲                      
  ╲   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i]
  ╱                     
 ╱                      
 ‾‾‾                    
i = 1
>>> s.subs(d, range(1, 6)).doit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/concrete/summations.py", line 189, in doit
    newf = eval_sum(f, (i, a, b))
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/concrete/summations.py", line 824, in eval_sum
    if i not in f.free_symbols:
  File "/home/artem/prog/dev/my_slot/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 494, in free_symbols
    return set().union(*[a.free_symbols for a in self.args])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'free_symbols'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in SymPy. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12532) for it.

A workaround is to specify the limits to the `Sum` instead of the `Idx`:

```
>>> i = Idx('i')
>>> s = Sum(d[i], (i, 1, n))
>>> s.subs(n, 5)
Sum(d[i], (i, 1, 5))
>>> s.subs(n, 5).doit()
d[1] + d[2] + d[3] + d[4] + d[5]
```

Substituting the `IndexedBase` for a list is another [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12533). Here is a workaround to make that work:

```
>>> l = range(6)
>>> s.subs(n, 5).doit().replace(Indexed, lambda i, j: Indexed(i, j) if i != d else l[j])
15
>>>
```

Note that your original doesn't work because it is using 1-based indexing on the range, but Python uses 0-based indexing, so you either need to increase the range, as I did, or modify your sum to go from 0 to n - 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a workaround for substituting the `IndexedBase` for a list?